# How do I display a picture in Django's DetailView based on a foreign key relationship?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am currently building a website with Django that will host music and album/song details. My models are set up so that each song has a foreign key to it's associated album, or to a database object titled "Singles" if they are not part of an album.

This relationship between song and album has worked great while building the site, until I got to the 'Play Song' page I am currently working on. Each Single has an associated artwork in the 'Song' model, while each song in an album has no 'picture' in the database, as the 'picture' is a part of the Album model and not the Song model in these instances. I am attempting to pass data from both the Song model and the Album model into my DetailView so that if the song being played is from an album rather than a single, it takes the 'picture' from the Album model it has a foreign key to rather than from it's own internal 'picture' object. My code is below, it renders the 'picture' for Singles perfectly, but cannot render the 'picture' object from the album and instead shows my {% else %} condition of a object not found picture. The HTML file has the logic I am using to find the associated picture:

```
{% elif song in album.song_set.all %}
<img src="{{ album.picture.url }}">
```

Any help would be appreciated.

### models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Must be at least two characters.")]
    )
    release_date = models.DateField()
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='albums/', blank=True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, help_text='The MIMEType of the file')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(2, "Must be at least two characters.")]
    )
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    length = models.CharField(
        max_length=200)
    featured_artists = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='singles/', blank=True)
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, help_text='The MIMEType of the file')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    alb = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='music_audio/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### views.py

```
class PlaySongView(DetailView):
    model = Song
    template_name = 'music/play_song.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PlaySongView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['album'] = Album.objects.exclude(title="Single")
        return context
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MusicView.as_view(), name='music'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.AlbumDetailView.as_view(), name='album_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/play', views.PlaySongView.as_view(), name='play')
]
```

### play_song.html

```
{% load static tailwind_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>LewnyToons - {{ song.title }}</title>
{% tailwind_css %}
</head>
    <body class="antialiased text-slate-400 bg-slate-900"> 
        <div class="w-full sm:w-9/12 lg:w-8/12 px-4 sm:pr-2 lg:pr-4 mx-auto"> 
            <div class="flex flex-col font-bold text-2xl text-center items-center text-white mx-auto pt-2">
                <h1 class="mb-4">Listen to {{ song.title }} now!</h1>
                {% if song.picture %}
                <img src="{{ song.picture.url }}" class="min-h-64 min-w-64 md:h-96 md:w-96"alt="">
                {% elif song in album.song_set.all %}
                <img src="{{ album.picture.url }}" class="min-h-64 min-w-64 md:h-96 md:w-96"alt="">
                {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'something_wrong.jpg' %}" class="min-h-64 min-w-64 md:h-96 md:w-96"alt="">
                {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% if song.audio_file %}
            <span class="flex justify-center py-10">
                <div>
                <audio controls><source src="{{ song.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
                </div>
            </span>
            {% else %}
            <p>The file could not be found.</p>
            <a href="{% url 'the_music:music' %}" class="text-white bold_underline">Return to music.</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies within the album context passed to the template in `PlaySongView.get_context_data()`.

You are passing a QuerySet of albums instead of the album object the song is related to. So when you try to do `album.song_set.all`, you're running that on a QuerySet instead of an Album object. The condition is not met, hence the fallback to the else block.

Instead of:

```
context['album'] = Album.objects.exclude(title="Single")
```

A better way to approach this in `get_context_data()` would be:

```
song = self.get_object()
context['album'] = song.alb
```

[`self.get_object()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) will look for a pk in your URL kwargs (in this case, `'<int:pk>/play'`) and lookup the song based on its primary key.

Then in your template, it's as simple as doing:

```
{{ album }}
```

There is no need to do a reverse relation in the template here because you have direct access to the album from your song DetailView with `self.get_object()`. Plus, this way you're not making unnecessary queries by fetching all your albums and passing them as context to the template. All you need is that 1 album.

As a general rule of thumb: if you can accomplish what you need query-wise in the view, it's typically a more optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I appreciate the additional insight on query sets, there are a few in this project I should modify to limit extra query's.